# USB Flash Drive Issue (not mounting or recognized)

Tags: usb, mount, flash, drive

I have the following issue with the USB flash drive:

```
[45343.578024] usb 4-6: new high-speed USB device number 120 using ehci-pci
[45343.607025] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=c08a, bcdDevice=10.75
[45343.607028] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[45343.607030] usb 4-6: Product: ADATA USB Flash Drive
[45343.607032] usb 4-6: Manufacturer: ADATA
[45343.607034] usb 4-6: SerialNumber: 27C1922460110037
[45343.607364] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[45343.607499] scsi host8: usb-storage 4-6:1.0
[45344.261557] usb usb4-port6: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[45344.261573] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 120
```

The flash drive is not shown in GParted, Disks and in the file manager.

Also not with `lsblk`:

```
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  69,9G  0 part /
└─sda2   8:2    0 861,7G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Any idea if the flash drive could be saved or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disabled by hub (EMI?)` message indicates a hardware issue, most probably with the flash drive but possibly also with the USB port, hub, or cabling.

To exclude cable, hub, or port issues, try plugging the flash drive into a different USB port directly on your computer without any intervening hubs and cables. If the same error still occurs then the flash drive is very probably defective and cannot be saved.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did insert the flash drive in other USB 2 and 3 ports and same problem. Looks like the flash drive is dead.